# Control running of transactions via Hyperledger composer ACL

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to figure out how to control the running of a transaction via the ACL rather than programmatically.

e.g. if I have two participants, Buyer and Seller, and one transaction to list an item to sell. I want to configure an ACL rule that says only a Seller can run the transaction to list an item. If a Buyer runs the transaction then it should be denied. Simplified declarations are as follows.

```
participant Person identified by emailId {
  o String emailId
}

participant Buyer extends Person {
}

participant Seller extends Person {
}

asset listing identified by item {
o string item
o double price
--> Seller
}

transaction list {
o listing itemtosell
--> Seller seller
}
```

best regards,
Jamil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want a rule similar to this to implement your solution:

```
rule EnableSellersList {
description: "Enable Sellers to use list"
participant: "org.acme.testorg.Seller"
operation: ALL
resource: "org.acme.testorg.list"
action: ALLOW
}
```

But the rule is part of a set, and you would need to make sure that there wasn't some other general rule that allowed access to Buyers.

There is a [good tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/acl-trading) in the Composer docs that goes through setting an ACL on a Transaction (as well as other useful ACLs).

There is also a [reference doc](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language) for the Access Control Language.

Comment: thanks, combining this with another deny rule does the job. I have had a look thru the docs you suggested. I am looking for details on the condition clause.  Methods such as getIdentifier() are available to be called, I have seen examples where .includes(), .some() are used. Is there any reference which lists and details all the methods that can be used ? or are these coded individually in script files by developers ?

Comment: yes, the JS documentation. You need to know the class/object to know what methods (like `getIdentifier()` ) are available to you in an ACL condition - see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/jsdoc/module-composer-runtime.html  in any case, You could even write your own custom functions and call these functions with parameters passed to it in the condition statement - such as here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-tests-functional/systest/data/accesscontrols.acl#L124